# Jenkins QC plugin Can't create TDConnection Object

Tags: jenkins, hp-quality-center

I'm attempting to use the Jenkins QC plugin, but when I build on jenkins i'm getting the following console errors

Started by user anonymous

Building in workspace C:\Users\builder.jenkins\workspace\QC Plugin
[QC Plugin] $ cscript /nologo "C:\Users\builder.jenkins\workspace\QC Plugin\runTestSet.vbs" http://**************  Caine test test qcreport-test-4.xml 100 RUN_PLANNED_HOST
C:\Users\builder.jenkins\workspace\QC Plugin\runTestSet.vbs(163, 5) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'TDApiOle80.TDConnection'

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : Script parameters:

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : *************************************************

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC Server : *******

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC UserName : *****

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC Password : ********

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC Domain : ******

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC Project : *****

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC TestSetFolder: test

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : QC TestSetName : test

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : XML Junit File : qcreport-test-4.xml

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : Timeout : 100

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : *************************************************

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : RunMode : RUN_PLANNED_HOST

5/30/2012 2:55:04 PM : *************************************************

Can't create TDConnection Object

Creating report...

Generating report file

Report file path: qcreport-test-4.xml

| Test Name | Status |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Report Created

FATAL: Couldn't run tests

Build step 'HP Quality Center' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE

Anyone any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems [known](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9539) but not fixed. It seems like the problem is of [32 vs 64 bits](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=479531) and has a workaround.

There are also other potential explanations, like [privileges](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/ActiveX-component-can-t-create-object-TDApiOle80-TDConnection/td-p/4742677#.UhJ8kWRNvs8)